# Pyserial returning sent string

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am writing a script to interface with a measurement device in a lab. The device sends and receives hex messages. Each time I send a message however, the read function simply returns the message that I sent (which is not what I'm expecting).

Sample code:

```
import serial, time

ser = serial.Serial(
    '/dev/cu.usbserial',
    baudrate = 19200, 
    bytesize = 8, 
    timeout = 3, 
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE, 
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE, 
)

if(ser.isOpen() == False):
    ser.open()

print 'Enter your commands below.\r\nInsert "exit" to leave the application.'

message = "\x02\x17\x00\x9A\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x3A\xA6"
message = bytearray([0x01,0x17,0x00,0x9A,0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3A, 0xA6])
for i in message:
    print hex(i)

while 1 :
    # get keyboard input
    input = raw_input(">> ")

    if input == 'exit':
        ser.close()
        exit()
    else:
        ser.write(message)
        print message
        chars = []
        out = '>> ' 

        time.sleep(3)

        chars += ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
        for i in chars:
            print i.encode("hex")
```

Prints to console:

```
01
17
00
9a
00
02
00
00
00
00
00
3a
a6
```

I'm wondering if this is a common issue in serial communications? i.e. such behaviour is indicative of a particular issue. Thanks!

Comment: it depends, because in serial communication you may have so-called 'local echo' and 'remote echo'
both of those things are usable, local one is just to see what you have typed, have no consequence because data sent to remote peer is not returned immediately
but remote echo is returning data from the remote device - this is sometimes used to validate that data was sent properly
pyserial's miniterm e.g has a -e flag